# Can I relate one-to-one to a key-value model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider this Django schema:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # ...

class FooOption(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(foo, related_name='options')
    key = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    value = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('foo', 'key')]
```

Essentially, `FooOptions` works a key-value set for each `Foo`.

<edit>

- There's a known set of *keys* that the system uses,
- Every Foo has a number of (key, value) pairs, where values are arbitrary,
- Or equivalently, Every Foo *can* have one value for every single *key*.

</edit>

As there's limited number of `key`s in `FooOption`, I'd like to rephrase this relation a bit using Django's ORM. The current design pictures the relation as a 1-n between a `Foo` and `FooOption`s; I'd like the code to picture it as 1-1 between a `Foo` and each specific `FooOption` key.

This would allow me to access each options like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # ...
    opt1 = OptionField('colour')
    opt2 = OptionField('size')

foo = Foo()
foo.opt1 = 'something'
foo.save()
```

Especially, I'd like to be able to `select_related` specific `FooOption`s when querying for many `Foo`s, to obtain an ORM-ed equivalent of:

```
SELECT foo.*, opt_colour.value, opt_size.value
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN foo_option opt_colour
  ON foo.id = foo_option.foo_id AND foo_option.key = 'id'
LEFT JOIN foo_option opt_size
  ON foo.id = foo_option.foo_id AND foo_option.key = 'size';
```

Is it possible to code such custom `OptionField`? How?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting your design, but it looks like you should actually be going with a [Many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) relationship.  You seem to want to have multiple options for each Foo instance (i.e. colour, size, etc.) and I imagine you would want a specific colour or size to be available to describe various Foo's.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    options = models.ManyToManyField('FooOption')
    # Other attributes.

class FooOption(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    value = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('key', 'value')]
```

Comment: Also note that, if you do go with ManyToMany, `select_related()` no longer works and you'll need to use `prefetch_related()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Joseph! My values don't aren't options to choose from, and they aren't unique together with Keys. Does my edit make my model any clearer?

Comment: @Chad `prefetch_related()` does a completely different thing; I can use it in my current design but it isn't helpful. `select_related` is closer in nature to what I want to achieve (left joins on the db side).